# Сколько словосочетаний со связью примыкание?

Tags: словосочетания, синтаксис

Сколько словосочетаний со связью примыкание?

> Число иностранных граждан, которые
> будут получать образование в вузах
> нашей страны, неуклонно растет. Это
> связано в первую очередь с
> политической и экономической
> стабильностью, демократическими
> преобразованиями в стране. Иностранные
> граждане изъявляют желание учиться в
> такой цветущей и спокойной стране, как
> Россия.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Два.

Примыкание: *неуклонно растёт*; *желание учиться* - инфинитив в роли несогласов. определения;

*будут получать* - не словосочетание, а форма глагола будущего времени;

*которые будут получать* - грамматическая основа, не словосочетание.

Comment: Про инфинитив совсем забыла..спасибо что помогли)

Comment: Рада, что помогла).Всего доброго.